# Power Query M combine multiple sources into one table

Tags: excel, import, powerquery, m

I'm brand new to Power Query and M (thanks to my company finally moving away from Office 2010...) and I'm trying to do import the content of multiple folders that are spread in different paths (I can't group them into one folder which would have made things easier.)

The content consists of tables in specific sheets (all named "Sheet1" for the purpose of this example). I have tried opening the advanced editor and wrote this code:

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\Nasen1030\subfolders\Workbook_1.xlsm"), null, true),
    Data1 = Source1{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]

    Source2 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\Nasen1030\subfolders\Workbook_2.xlsm"), null, true),
    Data2 = Source2{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]

    #"TableAppend" = Table.Combine(Data1, Data2)

in
    #"TableAppend"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and yields something like "Token Comma expected" with an arrow pointing in between Source2 and Data2.

Any idea why this would happen ? I've searched quite some time but can't find many examples of reading multiple files at different paths ... I expect to do this operation quite often, which is why I'm trying to define some code for it.

Thanks !

Comment: Use Custom Functions as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74535741/how-to-combine-multiple-web-requests-into-one-query-table

Answer (score 0):

Answer found: I forgot to add the curly brackets in`Table.Combine({Data1, Data2})` as well as the commas after each line in the `let` area.