# How to combine multiple web requests into one query/table?

Tags: powerbi, calendar, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I want to create a Canadian holiday calendar for multiple years. For this, I'm using [canada-holidays.ca/api](https://canada-holidays.ca/api). The thing is, if I want multiple years, I need to create a request for each year and then append them but doing so create a lot of requests that I don't want or need.

That's why I'm trying to integrate multiple source at the same time in a single query in Power Query.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297175/power-query-m-combine-multiple-sources-into-one-table) as an inspiration for what I want to do but it is based on Excel so it needs to be adjusted a bit.

That's why, I wrote this code :

```
let
//2021 Holidays
    Source1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://canada-holidays.ca/api/v1/holidays?year=2021")),
    #"Converti en table1" = Table.FromRecords({Source1}),
    #"ExpandList1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converti en table1", "holidays"),
    #"ExpandRecord1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ExpandList1", "holidays", {
        "id", 
        "date", 
        "nameEn", 
        "nameFr", 
        "federal", 
        "observedDate"}, {
            "id", 
            "date", 
            "nameEn", 
            "nameFr", 
            "federal", 
            "observedDate"}),
    #"Type modifié1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"ExpandRecord1",{
        {"id", Int64.Type}, 
        {"date", type date}, 
        {"nameEn", type text}, 
        {"nameFr", type text}, 
        {"federal", Int64.Type}, 
        {"observedDate", type date}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié1", each (
        [nameEn] = "Boxing Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Canada Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Christmas Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Day of Mourning for Queen Elizabeth II" or 
        [nameEn] = "Easter Monday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Good Friday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Labour Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "National Day for Truth and Reconciliation" or 
        [nameEn] = "New Year’s Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Remembrance Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Saint-Jean-Baptiste Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Thanksgiving" or 
        [nameEn] = "Victoria Day")),

//2022 Holidays
    Source2 = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://canada-holidays.ca/api/v1/holidays?year=2022")),
    #"Converti en table2" = Table.FromRecords({Source2}),
    #"ExpandList2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converti en table2", "holidays"),
    #"ExpandRecord2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ExpandList2", "holidays", {
        "id", 
        "date", 
        "nameEn", 
        "nameFr", 
        "federal", 
        "observedDate"}, {
            "id", 
            "date", 
            "nameEn", 
            "nameFr", 
            "federal", 
            "observedDate"}),
    #"Type modifié2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"ExpandRecord2",{
        {"id", Int64.Type}, 
        {"date", type date}, 
        {"nameEn", type text}, 
        {"nameFr", type text}, 
        {"federal", Int64.Type}, 
        {"observedDate", type date}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié2", each (
        [nameEn] = "Boxing Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Canada Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Christmas Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Day of Mourning for Queen Elizabeth II" or 
        [nameEn] = "Easter Monday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Good Friday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Labour Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "National Day for Truth and Reconciliation" or 
        [nameEn] = "New Year’s Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Remembrance Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Saint-Jean-Baptiste Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Thanksgiving" or 
        [nameEn] = "Victoria Day")),

    #"TableAppend" = Table.Combine({#"Lignes filtrées1"}, {#"Lignes filtrées2"})

in
    #"TableAppend"
```

Sadly, I have this error when I try to run it : "Expression.Error: The columns parameter must be null, specify the number of columns, specify a list of column names, or specify a table type.
Details:
[List]"

So, is there anyone who have an idea of what I can do to integrate multiple sources and append them in a single request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem:

1. Create a **Parameter** for Year and set it to 2021
2. Reference that parameter in your query for one year
3. Let PowerQuery create a **Custom function** from the result (right-click Create Function).
4. Enter all the years you are interested in a year column in another query
5. Add a new column by invoking your custom function and use the year column as parameter.
6. Expand the resulting tables and you're done

Read more about [Using custom functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/custom-function) in the official documentation.

This is how your **GetHolidays** custom function should look like:

```
(Year as text) =>
let
    Source1 = Json.Document(
        Web.Contents(
            "https://canada-holidays.ca/api/v1/holidays?year=" & Year
        )
    ),
    #"Converti en table1" = Table.FromRecords({Source1}),
    #"ExpandList1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converti en table1", "holidays"),
    #"ExpandRecord1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"ExpandList1", "holidays", {
        "id", 
        "date", 
        "nameEn", 
        "nameFr", 
        "federal", 
        "observedDate"}, {
            "id", 
            "date", 
            "nameEn", 
            "nameFr", 
            "federal", 
            "observedDate"}),
    #"Type modifié1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"ExpandRecord1",{
        {"id", Int64.Type}, 
        {"date", type date}, 
        {"nameEn", type text}, 
        {"nameFr", type text}, 
        {"federal", Int64.Type}, 
        {"observedDate", type date}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié1", each (
        [nameEn] = "Boxing Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Canada Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Christmas Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Day of Mourning for Queen Elizabeth II" or 
        [nameEn] = "Easter Monday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Good Friday" or 
        [nameEn] = "Labour Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "National Day for Truth and Reconciliation" or 
        [nameEn] = "New Year’s Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Remembrance Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Saint-Jean-Baptiste Day" or 
        [nameEn] = "Thanksgiving" or 
        [nameEn] = "Victoria Day"))
in
     #"Lignes filtrées1"
```

And this is your Holiday Calendar for all available years 2017-2026:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList({2017 .. 2026}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Year"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type", "GetHolidays", each GetHolidays([Year])),
    #"Expanded GetHolidays" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Invoked Custom Function", 
        "GetHolidays", 
        {"id", "date", "nameEn", "nameFr", "federal", "observedDate"}, 
        {"id", "date", "nameEn", "nameFr", "federal", "observedDate"}
    )
in
    #"Expanded GetHolidays"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just added some M-code to the answer.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot Peter!! It works so well!

I tried to do it by myself with the information you gave me but I wasn't able to create a parameter and I don't understand why.

So, again, thanks a lot for your answer. 

Also, could you just tell me how to enter multiple years in the GetHolidays function?

Comment: You can't (and if we would be back to your initial attempt). This is what the Holiday Calendar is made for. You get your multiple years with `Source = Table.FromList({2017 .. 2026}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Year"})`